# posts page - different lengths of excerpt

Tags: posts, pages, loop, templates

is it possible to get wordpress on the posts page to do the following example.

the first three posts need to have a large image spanning the width of the title box and a longer excerpt.

the rest of the posts need to be thinner and a smaller featured image floated left.

How would I go about changing this in the template or loop?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to filter [**`excerpt_length`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length).

Assuming you want your default excerpt length to be **50 words**:

```
<?php
function wpse53485_filter_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse53485_filter_excerpt_length' );
?>
```

That will make *all* excerpts 50 words. Make sure that works *first*.

Then, add in an appropriate conditional, to use a different excerpt length for a static page for posts. Assuming you use a custom page template, **named `template-posts.php`**, you could filter specifically for that page template, using [**`is_page_template()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template).

Assuming you want the page for posts to use an excerpt length of **100 words**:

```
<?php
function wpse53485_filter_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-posts.php' ) ) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return 50;
    }
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse53485_filter_excerpt_length' );
?>
```

Using this approach, you can conditionally return any number of excerpt lengths based on various contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Hard without having more info like how is your loop? Do you have two loops, one for the first 3 posts and a second for the rest ? Do you have one loop and assign a different markup with a counter ? Without having more info all that I can give to you to modify the excerpt is this:

Paste this on your functions.php file

```
function dp_clean($excerpt, $substr=0) {
    $string = strip_tags(str_replace('[...]', '...', $excerpt));
    if ($substr>0) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $substr);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

And then use this `<?php echo dp_clean($post->post_content, 250); ?>`

change 250 to some value to suit your needs